# Ordenacion ascedente en Angular2

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Necesito ordenar en mi código el que tiene mayor `idAcceso` es el que debe aparecer el primero (ASC)

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import{orderFields} from 'Lodash';

@Pipe({
    name: 'accesbyOrder',

})
export class AccesbyOrder implements PipeTransform {
    transform(array:Array<any>,filter:any,orderFields:string): Array<any>        
    {         
        array.forEach(function(currentField){
            var orderType='ASC';
        })

        array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {      
            if(filter == 'idAcceso'){
                if(a.idAcceso<b.idAcceso){
                   return -1;
                } else if (a.idAcceso > b.idAcceso) {
                      return 1;
                } else {
                  return 0;
                 }
              }
            else if(filter=='linea'){
                if (a.linea< b.linea) {
                    return -1;

                } else if (a.linea< b.linea) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });

        return array;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Este pipe lo uso para ordenar de forma ascendente y descendente:

```js
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'orderBy'
})

export class OrderByPipe {
  transform(value: Array<any>, args: any[]): any {
    let field: string = args.toString();
    if(value==null) {
      return null;
    }
    if (field.startsWith("-")) {
      field = field.substring(1);
      if (typeof value[field] === 'string' || value[field] instanceof String) {
        return [...value].sort((a, b) => b[field].localeCompare(a[field]));
      }
      return [...value].sort((a, b) => b[field] - a[field]);
    }
    else {
      if (typeof value[field] === 'string' || value[field] instanceof String) {
        return [...value].sort((a, b) => -b[field].localeCompare(a[field]));
      }
      return [...value].sort((a, b) => a[field] - b[field]);
    }
  }
}
```

En el html para ordenar:

```html
<div *ngFor="item of array | orderBy:'price'; let i = index">/*ascendente*/
<div *ngFor="item of array | orderBy:'-price'; let i = index">/*descendente*/
```